# Spring MVC 3, Interceptor on all excluding some defined paths

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

Is it possible to apply an interceptor to all controllers and actions, except some that are defined?

Just to be clear, I am not interested in applying an interceptor on a list of defined ones. I want to define those to exclude.

Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Since Spring 3.2 they added that feature with the tag

```
mvc:exclude-mapping
```

See this example from the Spring documentation:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/admin/**"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/secure/*"/>
    <bean class="org.example.SecurityInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Here's the [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors) to the doc

Comment: Make sure the xsd points to 3.2. I spent ten minutes trying to figure out what is wrong.  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

Answer (score 25):

For java based configuration, from the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new ThemeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/admin/**");
        registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/secure/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: Where the XML equivalent is presented as: `... <bean class="org.example.SecurityInterceptor"/> ...` - just for others to know that _SecurityInterceptor_ is not a springframework class.

Answer (score 3):

When configuring an interceptor, you can specify a path pattern. The interceptor will be invoked only for controllers which the path matches the interceptor path pattern.

ref: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptor

But as you probably noticed it, the path pattern doesn't support exclusion.

So I think the only way is to code a blacklist of paths inside the interceptor. When the interceptor is invoked, retrieve the `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` and check if the path is blacklisted or not.

You can build the blacklist inside a `@PostConstruct` annotated method of the interceptor, and so get the blacklisted path from a property file for instance.

Comment: Yes, the question is what the proper way would be to determine the controller and action since the controller mappings can theoretically  be build up in various ways... spring knows what the controller is to be fired after the interceptor, since the handler object is the controller instance. To properly do this one would have to look it up using the same mechanism that spring does to determine the target action... any one?? :)

Comment: The mechanism used by Spring to determine the right controller rely on the `@RequestMapping` annotation. So to have the same thing for interceptors mean basically annotating an interceptor with `@RequestMapping`. But this is not possible currently.