# Will preHandle method of Interceptor handle ajax calls also?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have written a preHandle method that will check the URL for a token and it works fine.

But will the same work for ajax calls?

```
 public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,final Object handler) throws Exception {
            String requesttoken = request.getParameter("token");
            if (requesttoken != null && validatetoken(requesttoken)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("/404.html");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That depends on the pattern you are applying the interceptor on.

Comment: Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: Will response.sendRedirect() method redirect ajax calls also?

Comment: Show us some code, please

Comment: yes it should redirect.

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990378/interceptor-prehandle-not-redirecting-to-login-html) answer

Comment: I don't want to use Controllers. On searching found a way of adding headers to the response and validating at client side.But since its a redirection the custom headers are getting replaced. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the interceptor will work for ajax calls as long as the pattern matches. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33729938/3094731) SO answer.

If you want to exclude ajax calls you can exclude the patterns like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ThemeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/ajax/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when the interceptor's pre-handle returns true? Will it follow the flow of Controller and return the View?

Comment: @SuprajaKumaravel : yes it will